# zf2 view strategy, ViewEvent Renderer is always null

Tags: zend-framework2

I am trying to implement View Strategy in ZF2.

As far as the basic setup, everything seem to be working fine except that ViewEvent Renderer is always null, thus the renderer never gets injected to the Strategy, and TemplateResolver still requests a template and displays the following error.

```
PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "api/api/get"; resolver could not resolve to a file'
```

I have even tried to copy the code JsonModel and JsonStrategy from ZF2, and still get the same result.
**ViewYamlStrategy.php**

```
public function selectRenderer(ViewEvent $e)
{
    $renderer = $e->getRenderer(); // Always return null
}
```

**module.php**

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return ['factories' => [
        'ViewYamlRenderer' => "Namespace\Mvc\Service\ViewYamlRendererFactory",
        'ViewYamlStrategy' => "Namespace\Mvc\Service\ViewYamlStrategyFactory",
        ],
    ];
}
```

**module.config.php**

```
'view_manager' => [
    'strategies' => [
        'ViewYamlStrategy'
    ],
],
```

**controller**

```
public function getList()
{
    return new YamlModel($data);
}
```

**ViewYamlStrategy.php**

```
function __construct(ViewYamlRenderer $renderer)
{
    $this->renderer = $renderer;
}
public function attach(EventManagerInterface $events, $priority = 1)
{
    $this->listeners[] = $events->attach(ViewEvent::EVENT_RENDERER, [$this, "selectRenderer"], $priority);
    $this->listeners[] = $events->attach(ViewEvent::EVENT_RESPONSE, [$this, "injectResponse"], $priority);
}

public function selectRenderer(ViewEvent $e)
{
    $renderer = $e->getRenderer();
    if ($this->renderer !== $renderer) {
        return;
    }
}

public function injectResponse(ViewEvent $e)
{
    $renderer = $e->getRenderer(); // Always null

    if ($this->renderer !== $renderer) {
        return;
    }
    $result = $e->getResult();
    $response = $e->getResponse();
    $response->setContent($result);
}
```

**ViewYamlRenderer.php**

```
public function render($nameOrModel, $values = null)
{
    return $nameOrModel->serialize();
}

public function setResolver(\Zend\View\Resolver\ResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $this->resolver = $resolver;
}
```

**YamlModel.php**

```
protected $captureTo = null;
protected $terminate = true;

public function serialize()
{
    /*Serialize Object and return a string*/
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the issue.

**ViewYamlStrategy.php**

```
/* This should return a renderer */
public function selectRenderer(ViewEvent $e)
{
    // here I was checking the Renderer which was not created yet
    // and instead I should've checked the model
    $model = $e->getModel();
    if (!$model instanceof YamlModel) {
        return;
    }
    return $this->renderer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is due to the order that the strategies/listeners are triggered; As once a `ViewRender` is found the event propagation is halted and that renderer is returned.

It seems that the standard `PhpRenderStrategy` has a *default* event priority of `1` and the others (`JsonStrategy` etc) seem to fire *prior* to this (with an even priority of `100`)

Try changing the `$priority`; perhaps `101`

```
$this->listeners[] = $events->attach(
  ViewEvent::EVENT_RENDERER, 
  [$this, "selectRenderer"], 
  101 // <-- change here
);
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this does not seem to work.
I think the whole issue is injecting the YamlRenderer to the View Event, since it is always null.